# Geolocation not working iOS

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, permissions, geolocation

I'm developing a hybrid mobile application and am trying to get HTML5 Geolocation working on iPhone IOS8, but am having no luck. Does anyone know any known problems? I've tried lots of examples but none are even prompting the user to allow geolocation. It works fine in browser, but as soon as upload to PhoneGap Build and install on my mobile it doesn't do anything.

Some example code i've tried is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

 <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 var x = document.getElementById("demo");

 function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     } else { 
         x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
     }
 }

 function showPosition(position) {
     x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
     "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I would use the PhoneGap plugin but couldn't get that working.

Thanks.

Comment: did you include the geolocation plugin?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yeah, i believe i've done it right. <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" /> i put that towards the top of my config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the command when **the device is ready**.

After, if the geolocation don't worked : try to use gyroscope plugins for a simple test .

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin for iOS and call them in config file

Download the Plugin from here :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git

```
 <feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

Hope this helps you